# Finding the index page using the admin panel of wordpress

Tags: homepage

I am helping out a non profit and they wanted some help in modifying the home page of their site .I looked around the admin area but I couldnt not find the index page anywhere so that I could make the changes.

Where should I be looking and if I cant find it from the admin page ,what other ways can I go about finding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [WordPress' Template Hierachy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). You will need to find which theme is active, and investigate the theme files.

Also check Settings → Reading to see if a static page is being set as the homepage. If it is not it should be one of the following template files:

- index.php
- home.php
- front-page.php

Hope that helps!